# How to install dev certs and run as HTTPS on non-dev machine?

Tags: asp.net-core, https, deployment, ssl-certificate, publish

I am publishing my ASP.NET Core 2.2 to a local location, then zipping it and trying to run on another machine. The other machine when launching does not show listening on HTTPS, only HTTP.

This is making the app not work. Locally on my dev machine I get both endpoints. I understand that I have to possibly use `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` or similar command but since my build is `self-contained` I really do not want to install the .NET Core SDK on every machine I run this on just to get that command.

How can I make my app run with  endpoint on the other machine with the least hassle?

Update:
The following message is also shown in the launch console window:

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3] 
>   Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

Comment: You don't really want to use the dev certificates in a non-dev environment, as they're not built for that purpose. You'll need to generate a real certificate if you want to use HTTPS outside of a dev environment. I'd suggest looking into setting up [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) with your app, such that it can auto renew it's certificate every 90 days.

Comment: @JamieTaylor True, but the other computer is also just for testing out my app, its not a real client.

Comment: I would still set up a real certificate there. Otherwise, you'll only be able to confirm that your app works with invalid certificates

Comment: The dev cert is just a self-signed cert. You can create a self-signed cert on the other machine as well, but that self-signed cert must be added to the client's trusted cert store, or you'll still get HTTPS errors. Visual Studio takes care of this for you, but that's specifically for the purposes of development. You should not do the same in other situations. You might consider using something like https://letsencrypt.org/ instead.